# how to deal with doctrine updates on case insensitive file systems(?)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an issue with doctrine updates. When a new table is added the table name defaults to the class name (with upper case) 'class Foo', table created is 'Foo'. If you change Foo, such as add or delete a property, upon update, the table is renamed to 'foo'.

There is a bug filed against this issue: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-598

The issue is when I export and post the db to a linux based system (when exported from mac-os), I have to hand edit the export file to fix the db tables.

Specifically my question is, has anyone come up with a reasonably automated way of cleaning up the table names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define the table name in lower-case in the entity definition, e.g.:

**YAML:**

```
# Doctrine.Tests.ORM.Mapping.User.dcm.yml
Doctrine\Tests\ORM\Mapping\User:
    type: entity
    table: cms_users
```

**XML:**

```
// Doctrine.Tests.ORM.Mapping.User.dcm.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                          http://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Doctrine\Tests\ORM\Mapping\User" table="cms_users">
```

**Annotation:**

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User { }
```

That way you ensure that there's no problem whatsoever during a schema update on different filesystems.

Comment: Yeh, I guess it's easier to keep everything lower case. It'd be nicer if it was upper case, but you are right. Hm. I am going to have to try it, b/c on my mac it probably won't see the case as a change.

Comment: Confirmed. MacOS it doesn't see it as a change.

Comment: @user3325313 If it helped it would be nice if you would [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (and maybe [upvote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) as well). As you seem to be a new user here on SO, I would recommend [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to you. ;-)

Comment: I am not accepting the answer because it does not solve my problem and I do not have enough reputation to up vote. While the answer solves the problem for _new_ tables, existing tables cannot be updated to reflect the table case. I am stuck having to modify an export with a text editor, which is unwieldily.

Comment: @user3325313 Well, you could always use a [migration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/migration_classes.html) and write plain SQL to fix table names on existing projects. Another way would be to use e.g. phpMyAdmin (or some other tool) where table renaming normally is available as well. If that works for you, I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I resorted to editing an export (carefully), then hardcoding the table names. Not ideal as it was a nail biting experience, and the one I wanted to avoid. Thing is there are lots of constraints that had to be fixed along with it.

Comment: Warning: I was inclined to hard code my tables to the class names ('Thingy'), but I notice that doctrine (2.4) will force the name to lower (thingy) regardless of the table name specified if it alters the table on an update.